# Fill 100px DIV with exactly 10 characters, what is the font-size I should use?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have a DIV which is 100px in width, in each row, now I want to fill exactly 10 characters, what is the font-size I should use?

Comment: Depending on the font _family_ this will differ greatly.

Comment: It's also depending on the characters, a W is wider than a dot when you don't use a monospace-font.

Comment: In addition to the font family and characters, the OS and browser will also change the width. If this is dynamic text, and therefore you can't play around with it, use image replacement (something like sIFR). The only other alternative is to detect the rendered size with JavaScript and change if necessary.

Comment: whichever way you choose to do this, users will be able to break it by changing the font-size in their browser. It may be a better option to alter the design so that the exact font-size is not as critical.

Comment: If you explain a reason for wanting to do that, we might have a solvable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments to your question suggest, this is a bit messy to accomplish in a good way, since it vary between different fonts, OS, browser etc. However, one thing you could try to experiment with at least is putting the CSS-attribute `text-align: justify;` on your div.

If you put a space between each character, and choose the largest font-size where 10 characters fit on a single row. Then this CSS-attribute will make sure that the spacing between the characters are adjusted so that the characters fill out the entire div.

This is not a bullet-proof way of doing this, and it will probably still be broken for some users, but if you experiment with different browsers to find a suitable size, and have a bit of margin so that you don't necessarily choose the absolutely largest size that fits, then the adjusted spacing hopefully will take care of most variations between browsers, OS etc. Those who use increased font-size will however still have a problem.